# ternary operator with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, ternary-operator

I want to re-write the if and switch in another ternary operator

```
var result = fieldValue ? fieldValue.split("/") : null;
var res = null;
if (result.length > 0) {
  switch (label.toLowerCase()) {
    case "jenkins job name":
      res = result[result.length - 2];
      break;
    case "jenkins job number":
      res = result[result.length - 3];
      break;
  }
```

I am trying as below its not working, what am I doing wrong

```
result = fieldValue ? fieldValue.split("/") : null;
var res = result.length > 0 ? () => {
  switch (label.toLowerCase()) {
    case "jenkins job name":
      return result[result.length - 2];
    case "jenkins job number":
      return result[result.length - 3];
  }
} : null;
```

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: This looks like a misuse of the ternary operator to make things harder to read, but whatever. Use a IIFE, like `(function () { switch ... })()`.

Comment: You are not calling the function, therefore `res` will either be assigned a function or `null`.

Comment: I def agree with @MikeMcCaughan, not sure why you're doing this. Much easier to just use an if statement here.

Answer (score 2):

side note: If result is null you will get an exception when trying to get the length attribute of null consider changing to `fieldValue ? fieldValue.split("/") : ""`.

In order for both codes have the same result you should call the anonimous function like this:

```
var res = result.length > 0 ? (() => {
    switch (label.toLowerCase()) {
        case "jenkins job name" :
            return result[result.length - 2];
        case "jenkins job number" :
        return result[result.length - 3];
    }    
})() : null;
```